# how to implement AWS Media Convert with AWS s3 from node js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am building an app where the user can upload and see videos. I am storing the videos in .mp4 container format in S3, however, I want to convert the video to m3u8 format for adaptive streaming.

I found there is something called "Amazon MediaConvert" (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/index.html) which can do the job for me.

Have anyone tried using this AWS media convert services? I am struggling to implement this? can anyone guide? or if my approach is wrong

As per MediaConvert the basic flow is : 1. Get your account specific Endpoint 2. Create a transcoding job 3. Use job to transcode a video

I am stuck as step 2.

My objective is to convert the .mp4 videos to m3u8 in server side using node js. PLease help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a job template on the new Elemental Media Convert. This create different job profiles for you automatically. then once that is done, drop a source video file in the S3 bucket you specified for Media Convert to listen to when creating the template. This kicks off the transcoding process and the different video formats adapted for different screens and bandwidths are saved in the 'destination' bucket on S3 as specified in steps above.

Comment: From that point, go to CloudFront and create a distribution, although one is automatically made for you when you set up the job profiles. You can tweak the cloudfront delivery settings or leave them as they are. Grab the cloudfront domain name and that should be the host of your new url to serve edge-located videos in adaptive format

Comment: Hey Martin - once the video is encoded - how do you retrieve the cloudfront url for the videos you have encoded?